# How can I have skinnier pthreads?

Tags: c, memory-management, pthreads, ncurses

I have a really basic ncurses program to monitor machine statistics and launch remote xterms.  It just sits on a window all day and helps me choose a not-heavily-loaded machine to work on.  It works fine, and I love it dearly.  But it's really fat.  Much fatter than it needs to be, I think.

The program basically is as follows:

```
void * run(void * task) {
    // once per minute:
        popen( /* stats checking command */ )
        // save output to global var
        pclose
}

int main() {
    // setup ncurses with halfdelay
    for ( /* each machine */ ) 
        pthread_create(somethread, NULL, run, (void *)somestruct);
    while ( ( c = getch() ) != 'q' )
        for ( /* each machine */ ) 
            // print machine stats
        // maybe launch an xterm
    // die gracefully
}
```

And as stated above, it works just fine.  The problem is that each thread has all the ncurses baloney tucked in private memory leading to one very fat process with a boatload of wasted bits.

The question, then, is this:  how can I re-write or re-arrange this program so that each pthread doesn't carry around all the unnecessary ncurses stuff?

Side-question: You'll have to really sell me on it, but does anyone know of a better method than ncurses to do this?  I want the stats on fixed positions in the terminal window, not scrolling text.

Comment: "Each thread has all the ncurses baloney" - that's not at all clear from your code example!

Comment: The only part of the code that needs "ncurses baloney" is `//print machine stats` which is not in the threaded code. Are you sure the issue is with ncurses?

Comment: I suppose I don't know that for sure, no.  My assumption was that each thread was basically fork()ing the parent process and taking with it a lot of stuff not used in the thread's own task.  Also, I've updated the code to be more clear that the threads use popen() on a shell command to check the machine stats.  All I know for sure is that each thread adds ~8mb to the process's memory usage.  Is the problem in popen()?

Comment: @user340098: Threads are very heavy-weight objects. At the least, they must allocate memory for their stack (1-2MB on most systems). If you really want to be lightweight, you should use an event-driven architecture (using (for example) [select(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or a higher level interface doing the same thing).

Comment: The point of threads is that they're not anywhere near as "heavyweight" as forking a new process. They only create a new thread of execution in the process, a new stack and some amount of thread specific storage. They exist in the same address space as the other threads in the process, so they have access all the same data without copying anything. Unless ncurses is thread aware and specifically allocates storage for each thread, will it cause no additional overhead when you create threads.

Comment: Rather than creating a new thread for each stream, use asynchronous batch operations on the file handles (such as `poll(2)`, or `select(2)` like Mankarse suggested). In general, if you're making more than two threads (in total, including the one that starts with the process) for light work like this, then you should probably rethink your approach. Even a linear-time `select` operation won't take that much time, and almost no resources whatsoever when compared the the resources a few dozen pthreads would take.